# Simple string operations in C++

Tags: c++, strings, windows

I'm a .NET (C#/VB) developer who knows a little C and happens to need to write a native C++ Windows DLL.

Please have a look at the following code and tell me if the string operations are idiomatic C++:

```
int dpi;

void __stdcall FooEntryPoint(ENTRY_INFO* inEntryInfo)
{
    dpi = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(inEntryInfo->UserData);

    OutputDebugStringW((std::wstring(L"User Data supplied: ") + std::to_wstring(dpi)).c_str());

    FARPROC address = GetFooAddress();
    if (address == NULL)
    {
        OutputDebugStringW(L"Foo address not found.\n");
        return;
    }

    NTSTATUS result = FrobnicateFoo(address);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        OutputDebugStringW((std::wstring(L"Failed to frobnicate foo: ") + RtlGetLastErrorString() + L"\n").c_str());
    }
}
```

My thoughts on the matter:

- As a .NET developer, I'm used to *"Unicode is default unless there's a very good reason against it"*, and, thus, I just use `L"..."` string literals and `...W` API methods without giving it further thought.
- `(std::wstring(...) + ... + ...).c_str()` *seems* to be the simplest way in C++ to do string concatenations of wchar arrays (denoted as `...`) without having to worry about memory allocations. I could use `wostringstream`, but it would just make the code more complicated.
- I know that failing silently is bad practice, but the signature of `FooEntryPoint` is part of the interface contract I'm given, so this is "by design".

Does that make sense or am I violating any good C++ practices here?

Note: The code does not need to be portable.

Comment: What is `dpi`? Is that a global variable?

Comment: @CodyGray: Yes. Sorry, fixed. That happens when you fooify only part of your code...

Comment: AFAIK, Idiomatic C++ prefers exceptions over return-code-based error-handling.  `reinterpret_cast` is a huge red flag. You should question whether a weaker cast would do the job or whether a cast is necessary at all. Creating intermediary std::wstring objects only to output them is wasteful. Pure output shouldn't need to use dynamic memory.

Comment: @PSkocik: We're talking about a few bytes here. Isn't that a case of premature optimization? Or is it generally "good practice" in C++ to worry about such things?

Comment: IDK. I'd say preferring `stream<<(a+b+c+d);` over `stream<<a<<b<<c<<d;` is a premature pessimization given that the cheap version is basically just as terse as the more expensive one.

Comment: @PSkocik: Point taken. Nevertheless, since `OutputDebugStringW` requires a wchar*, I don't see how I can pass a concatenated string *without* dynamic memory.

Comment: @Heinzi please don't "foo-ify" code you post here. It can cause a lot of frustration for everyone. In fact, as it is, I'm going to have to VTC this as example code. Please read our help center.

Comment: @RubberDuck: You're obviously free to VTC as you please, but please consider the fact that I explicitly did *not* fooify the parts I want feedback on and the question does not contain *"purely generic, hypothetical code"*, as mentioned in the help center. I do get your point, but I'd be a bit pragmatic here - do you really think dumping a wall of unrelated code (which just happens to be in the vicinity of the code in question) or adding a long explanation of context with is irrelevant to the question (but required to understand the unfooed code snippet) improves the question?

Comment: @RubberDuck: I just found [this meta answer](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652) by following the link in the VTC reason. I did not find it in the help center. It all makes sense now, and I will heed the advice for my next question. I'm a bit hesitant to rewrite my question now since I don't want to invalidate the good answers I got. How do you propose I proceed?

Comment: @Heinzi given you received very good answers, I would take their advice and clean up your real code. At that point, you can either let sleeping dogs lie or post a new question if you'd like further feedback. Thanks for being so understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some thoughts:

- It is good that you explicitly annotated the function's definition with its required calling convention. Make sure that you do the same thing for the declaration in the public C++ header, and for the P/Invoke declaration (if applicable) in your .NET application.

  Calling convention mismatches are a common source of bugs, and you don't want to rely on the correct compiler flags (specifying the default calling convention) having to be specified in order for the code to work correctly.
- This line:

  ```
  dpi = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(inEntryInfo->UserData);
  ```

  hoists a giant red flag, for at least a couple of reasons:

  1. Why is `dpi` a global (module-scoped?) variable? It looks to me like it just needs to be a local variable. I'm assuming that you raised its scope so it would be usable within the `GetFooAddress` and/or `FrobnicateFoo` functions? If so, you should pass it as a *parameter* to these functions. Always keep the scope of variables to the minimum level necessary—this is the same rule as in C#/VB.NET, of course.
  2. That `reinterpret_cast` business is dicey. Reinterpretation casts are *always* a bit dicey, and this one especially, since it doesn't have a reassuring comment nearby that explains how it is safe. :-) You didn't show us the definition of the `ENTRY_INFO` type, so it's hard to confirm whether or not this actually *is* safe, but there really aren't that many cases where you can legitimately reinterpret a pointer to one primitive type as a pointer to another primitive type. If I had to guess, I'd say that `UserData` is a `void*`? If at all possible, you should just change it to be the `int*` that you ultimately want. The only advantage of a `void*` would be to achieve something akin to VB's Variant, but that requires some way to determine what the *actual* type is. Your code doesn't have that, it just *assumes* that the pointer is actually to an `int`. Lots of different ways that can go wrong. Hard to say exactly how you should fix this without more information, but definitely know that this smells funny and very likely hides a bug.
  3. Beyond the question of the cast, you are potentially dereferencing a null pointer, which is undefined behavior and *definitely* a bug. You need to be checking this explicitly, just like you are all of the other error conditions, unless you can *guarantee* that the caller will never pass you a null pointer (in which case, verify that assumption using an `assert`).
- > As a .NET developer, I'm used to *"Unicode is default unless there's a very good reason against it"*, and, thus, I just use `L"..."` string literals and `...W` API methods without giving it further thought.

  This is completely correct. In fact, this doesn't have anything to do with .NET; it is more precisely a Windows thing. The Windows operating system uses Unicode internally (at least, all versions of NT do, which means everything modern and semi-modern), and there is no reason to ever use narrow/ANSI strings unless you need the code to run on Windows 9x. Therefore, your adopted practices make very good sense.
- > `(std::wstring(...) + ... + ...).c_str()` *seems* to be the simplest way in C++ to do string concatenations of wchar arrays (denoted as `...`) without having to worry about memory allocations.

  Indeed, the `+` operator is the *simplest* way to concatenate strings in C++. However, it is not necessarily the most *efficient*. Use of the `+` operator is creating a bunch of temporaries, which the compiler may or may not be able to optimize out. In general, you should prefer the `+=` operator to help stave off the proliferation of temporary objects (or the `append` member function, which is slightly less terse, but may be easier to reason about because there are no operator precedence concerns).

  Also, not having to worry about memory allocations may be a curse disguised as a blessing. In general, pre-allocating the required amount of space (using the `reserve` member function) will net you better performance than letting the library code do incremental allocations as-needed, assuming of course that you have some idea in advance of how much space you will need.

  That said, neither of these things matter if the code you're writing is not performance-sensitive. And obviously this isn't, since it's calling `OutputDebugString`, which is a *very* slow function.

  > We're talking about a few bytes here. Isn't that a case of premature optimization? Or is it generally "good practice" in C++ to worry about such things?

  Yes, it is probably "good practice" in C++ to worry about such things. A major reason for people to write code in C++ is because they care about efficiency.
- > I could use `wostringstream`, but it would just make the code more complicated.

  Well, that is arguable, and I see that [πάντα ῥεῖ already made the argument](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/151241/121675). This is ultimately up to you: either will work, and since debug output is not performance-sensitive, there isn't a clear case to be made either way as far as I'm concerned. However, on the readability front, you can actually get a similar effect by using the `+=` operator (which I'd recommended anyway—see code below).

  I do want to quibble slightly with one thing πάντα ῥεῖ said, though—or at least, my interpretation of what he said… While it is, in general, completely true that more lines of code do not make a program slower or more complicated, using stream output *probably is* going to be slower than simple string concatenation. I would only resort to streams if I needed to *format* the output in some way.
- Also, speaking of `OutputDebugString`, this is almost certainly a function that you only want to call in debugging builds. It won't be conditionally compiled out like the equivalent `Debug` functions in .NET; you have to do this manually. The simplest way is to use a preprocessor conditional, something like:

  ```
  #ifdef DEBUG
      OutputDebugStringW(...)
  #endif  // DEBUG
  ```

  Another alternative would be to write your own `TRACE` macro (MFC and other commonly used C++ libraries have one included) that either expands to a call to `OutputDebugString` or to a no-op, depending on the build settings. For example:

  ```
  #ifdef DEBUG
      #define TRACE(str)    OutputDebugStringW(str)
  #else
      #define TRACE(str)    (void)(str)
  #endif  // DEBUG
  ```

  There are all sorts of ways to make this more complicated, more flexible, and more useful. In fact, you might not decide that you don't want to base it on the definition of a `DEBUG` preprocessor symbol at all, since you might want this debug trace available in an instrumented but otherwise optimized build. However, I would *not* recommend spewing a bunch of debug info in a shipping build. It is slow and unhelpful to the typical user.

  If you really need this information for remote debugging, you should almost certainly be writing it into a log file, instead, since `OutputDebugString` is effectively an expensive no-op if there is no debug listener attached! Investigate a logging framework for C++, or write your own if you have unlimited time on your hands. Either way, make it so that this "verbose" mode can be enabled as a run-time option at the request of your technical support staff.
- One last point about `OutputDebugString`: I personally believe that any string you pass to it should *always* end with a trailing new-line character. It doesn't get inserted automatically, so multiple back-to-back calls to `OutputDebugString`—even in completely different modules—will result in cluttered and unreadable output otherwise. A `TRACE` macro could certainly automatically append this `\n`, though.
- > I know that failing silently is bad practice, but the signature of FooEntryPoint is part of the interface contract I'm given, so this is "by design".

  Fair enough, but I have to again agree with πάντα ῥεῖ that you should be using an `assert` here for ease of debugging—unless that is, failure is an expected scenario.

  You should be aware, though, that idiomatic C++ would use exceptions for things like this that cannot reasonably be handled by the callee, just like idiomatic C#/VB.NET code. This wouldn't affect the signature (the function would still return `void`), but it would certainly affect the interface, so I realize that may not be an option for you.
- Instead of the `NULL` macro that you would use in C code, modern C++ code should prefer to use `nullptr` for a variety of reasons. You can basically use it as a drop-in replacement, with the advantage that it is a distinct type so it won't ever be ambiguous with the integer literal 0.
- I also like to obsessively make every local variable that I'm not going to change in subsequent code `const`. Although this doesn't really enable any additional optimizations, it makes it easier for me to reason about the code and increases the likelihood that the compiler will catch bugs. In fact, I'm of the opinion that `const` should have been the *default* for locals, and you should have had to explicitly mark them as `mutable` if you wanted that. As a case in point, I would make the `address` and `result` variables explicitly `const`.
- My last observation is almost purely stylistic, and probably at least somewhat controversial, but I would format the code differently to ensure only a single exit point. I'm not at all dogmatic about this, but I think in this particular case it is clearer to think about the operations you're doing in a chain or hierarchy, so it is natural to format them as a series of nested blocks:

  ```
  const FARPROC address = GetFooAddress();
  if (address != nullptr)
  {
      const NTSTATUS result = FrobnicateFoo(address);
      if (FAILED(result))
      {
      #ifdef DEBUG
          std::wstring str = (L"Failed to frobnicate foo: ");
          str += RtlGetLastErrorString();
          str += L"\n";
          OutputDebugStringW(str.c_str());
      #endif  // DEBUG
      }
  }
  else
  {
  #ifdef DEBUG
      OutputDebugStringW(L"Foo address not found.\n");
  #endif  // DEBUG
  }
  ```

  I'm neutral on whether the error condition (`address == NULL`) should come first, or whether the success condition should come first. There are readability arguments both ways. I tend to prefer putting the success condition first to increase the likelihood of successful static branch prediction, but that's becoming a non-issue on current generations of processors that don't simply assume "not taken" for all forward conditional jumps. [I just wrote a crazy-long answer about this that ultimately concludes it doesn't matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41382497/which-code-flow-pattern-is-more-efficient-in-c-net/41384539#41384539).

Comment: _"hoists a giant red flag, for at least a couple of reasons"_ Yes that's right. And I was about to mention that as well. Though it seems the code implements a predefined C-API plugin interface. In such cases you don't really have a choice.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: *"Though it seems the code implements a predefined C-API plugin interface, [...]"* - exactly. That's also the reason why `dpi` is a global variable: It's required at a later invocation of another method. (Yes, the order of execution is guaranteed by the interface contract.)

Comment: @Heinzi Let me gues: _Printer resolution_?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Screen resolution. I'm trying to [solve this issue](http://superuser.com/q/66101/14517) by hooking into GetDeviceCaps. First tests are very promising.

Comment: @Heinzi I'm assuming you are trying to do this for an application for which you do not have access to the source code? I'm skeptical of whether or not that is going to work. GetDeviceCaps doesn't control the DPI, it just returns the DPI for the device context that you pass to it. It will have no effect on the device context itself. I am rather shocked that you're getting results that seem promising. No amount of hooking GetDeviceCaps will affect the assumptions that the system is making...

Comment: @CodyGray: If GetDeviceCaps returns a larger DPI value, an "old-style DPI-aware" application will choose larger fonts and increase the spacing between elements - which is exactly the effect I want to achieve. My primary target are MS-Access-based LOB applications, and - apparently - MS Office is "old-style DPI aware" (i.e. not per-monitor DPI aware, which would use a different API).

Comment: Oh, I see. You're relying on Office actually doing the right thing, checking the DPI and adapting appropriately each time it displays some UI. Most applications won't do that, and even if you only care about Office, there are *still* so many ways this can go wrong it makes my stomach hurt. I guess I won't think about it any more, considering it isn't the question being asked here.

Answer (score 2):

> - As a .NET developer, I'm used to "Unicode is default unless there's a very good reason against it", and, thus, I just use L"..." string literals and ...W API methods without giving it further thought.

Nothing wrong with that so far. That's why the c++ standard supports the wide string literals and functions.

> - `(std::wstring(...) + ... + ...).c_str()` seems to be the simplest way in C++ to do string concatenations of wchar arrays (denoted as ...) without having to worry about memory allocations. I could use `wostringstream`, but it would just make the code more complicated.

Here I have to disagree. Using `wostringstream` would improve the readability a lot, and help to avoid creating intermediary `wstring` instances all the time.

Compare

```
 OutputDebugStringW((std::wstring(L"User Data supplied: ") + std::to_wstring(dpi)).c_str());
```

or

```
 OutputDebugStringW((std::wstring(L"Failed to frobnicate foo: ") + RtlGetLastErrorString() + L"\n").c_str());
```

with

```
 std::wostringstream oss;
 oss << L"User Data supplied: " << dpi;
 OutputDebugStringW(oss.str().c_str());

 // ...

 oss.str(L"");
 oss << L"Failed to frobnicate foo: " << RtlGetLastErrorString() << L"\n";
 OutputDebugStringW(oss.str().c_str());
```

from point of view of readability and clearness. Just writing a few more lines doesn't *make the code more complicated*.

> - I know that failing silently is bad practice, but the signature of FooEntryPoint is part of the interface contract I'm given, so this is "by design".

Well, you should at least assert that the passed pointers are valid. E.g. using

```
 std::assert(inEntryInfo);
```

before dereferencing it

```
 int* pdpi = reinterpret_cast<int *>(inEntryInfo->UserData);
 std::assert(pdpi);
 dpi = *pdpi;
```